# How to subset a dataset based on another dataset?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to subset the dataframe z that meets the following requirements:

1,remove the observations from dataframe z that the values of column 1 is not in the row-name of matrix y;

2,remove the observations from dataframe z that the values of column 2 is not in the column-name of matrix y.

The following is the code creating dataframe z and matrix y:

```
    ## a matrix y 

y<-matrix(1:12, nrow=3, ncol=4, dimnames = list(c("R1", "R2","R3"),c("C1", "C2","C3","C4") ))


## a dataframe z
col1<-c("R1", "R2","R3","R4","R5","R6","R7","R8","R9")
col2<-c("C1", "C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9")


z<- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

The form of datafram z is :
[data frame z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DZpM.png)

The form of matrix y is :
[matrix y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aOxh.png)

The ouput dataframe I want should be:

```
          col1     col2

1          R1       C1

2          R2       C2

3          R3       C3
```

I have no idea on how to subset the dataframe based on the row and column names of a matrix. Could anyone know how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
# Specification of z and y:

y<-matrix(1:12, nrow=3, ncol=4, dimnames = list(c("R1", "R2","R3"),c("C1", "C2","C3","C4") ))

col1<-c("R1", "R2","R3","R4","R5","R6","R7","R8","R9")
col2<-c("C1", "C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9")

z<- data.frame(col1,col2)

# extract subset:

col.in.y.row = ( z[,1] %in% row.names(y) ) 

col.in.y.col = ( z[,2] %in% colnames(y) )

data.frame(z, col.in.y.row, col.in.y.col)

(z.subsetted = z[ col.in.y.row & col.in.y.col, ])
```

Comment: Thank you @floattube . It works! One more small question is that why  do we need to add a comma in `z[ col.in.y.row & col.in.y.col, ]` ? whtat does that mean?

Comment: Since z is a dataframe, `z[a, b]` means that you are selecting row a, column b. So when the column is not specified, it just selects all the columns corresponding to that row.